# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'series' python error

Tags: python, dataframe

This is my code and I keep getting this error and I am not sure how to fix it. I am probably calling the method wrong. The problem is to: Use Series method describe to calculate the descriptive statistics for the categorical data (text) columns from the dataset.

my code:

```py
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv('Housing.csv', index_col = 0)
print('Description: ', df.describe())
print('Series description: ', df.Series.describe())
print('Histograms: ', df.hist(figsize = (8, 8)))
print('Series description: ', df.series.describe())
```

Comment: We need more code than that.  What type of object is `df`?  How is it created?

Comment: Here is everything I have so far. It is not completed but hopefully it will give you what you need.

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Housing.csv', index_col = 0)


print('Description: ', df.describe())
      
print('Series description: ', df.Series.describe())
      
print('Histograms: ', df.hist(figsize = (8, 8)))

Comment: Heather: Please put the code in your question where it belongs.

Comment: Your code has both `df.series` and `df.Series`.  Which is it?

Comment: It should be `Series` instead of `series`

Comment: Show what your dataframe looks like by updating the question

Answer (score 1):

The dataframe includes columns, each of which are series, but the dataframe itself is not a series.  Looks like you want to describe the entire df, then describe particular columns.  If so, pick each individual column to describe, because those columns are series.  See this toy example:

```
row1list = ['$500 -', 'www']
row2list = ['$4.00 -', 'xyz']
df = pd.DataFrame([row1list, row2list],
                  columns=['Price', 'abc'])

print(df.describe)
# <bound method NDFrame.describe of      Price  abc
# 0   $500 -  www
# 1  $4.00 -  xyz>

print(df['Price'].describe())
# count           2
# unique          2
# top       $4.00 -
# freq            1
# Name: Price, dtype: object
```